# Replace Xalan with Saxon for XSL with Java-Extension

Tags: xslt, saxon, xalan

I have several XSL-transformations in a business process with Xalan where one of these steps produces XSL-Stylesheets with static Java extension functions.

I want to replace Xalan with Saxon (not only for performance issues but for the use of XSLT2 too).

I know what to change in XSL to get Saxon to use the functions. And it works very well (with Xalan-optimized XSL I get a speedup of 40 and only half use of RAM).

My problem is that these generated XSL-Stylesheets are "cached"/stored in huge amounts and it would be a mega pain (or impossible) to "refresh" them.

**My question is if I can manage to get the XSLs to work with Saxon without changing them or preprocess the XML (modifying SAX-Parser or StringReplacing etc.)?**

At the moment I need to change the namespace and the function calls because with Xalan I used the package in the namespace and Saxon (seems to) wants the class.

I have full control over the package and class structure and code of "de.server.macro".

(For testing) I'm using Saxon-9B but finally it would be Saxon-PE or Saxon-EE.

Here are my minimalized examples:

**Xalan**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns:macro="xalan://de.server.macro">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:text>Hello World!</xsl:text>
        <mymacro>
            <xsl:variable name="foo">5</xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="macro:data.setVar('testdata', $foo)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="macro:data.getVar('testdata')"/>
        </mymacro>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
```

**Saxon**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns:macro="de.server.macro.data">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:text>Hello World!</xsl:text>
        <mymacro>
            <xsl:variable name="foo">5</xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="macro:setVar('testdata', $foo)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="macro:getVar('testdata')"/>
        </mymacro>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
```

I know about http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions.html and http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/extensibility/functions/staticmethods.html and several other sources (blog posts and books) about xslt-extensions but based on these informations it looks like the answer is "no".

but perhaps I miss something or some possible mapping mechanisms in Saxon to simulated the right behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following solution for my (specific) problem:
I post two variants because there are several differences between Saxon-B (v9.1.0.8) and Saxon-EE (v9.6.0.7).

Adding my special FunctionLibrary before all other existing FunctionLibrarys to ensure the default handling when my special case is not triggered:

*Saxon-B*

```
net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl saxonFactory = (net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl)tFactory;
FunctionLibraryList fll = new FunctionLibraryList();
fll.addFunctionLibrary( new OldXalanFunctionLibrary() );
fll.addFunctionLibrary( saxonFactory.getConfiguration().getExtensionBinder("java") );
saxonFactory.getConfiguration().setExtensionBinder("java", fll);
```

*Saxon-EE*

```
net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl saxonFactory = (net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl)tFactory;
FunctionLibraryList fll = new FunctionLibraryList(); 
fll.addFunctionLibrary( new OldXalanFunctionLibrary() );
ProfessionalConfiguration conf = (ProfessionalConfiguration)saxonFactory.getConfiguration();
fll.addFunctionLibrary( conf.getExtensionBinder("java") );
conf.setExtensionBinder("java", fll);
```

My special handling FunctionLibrary looks like:

*Saxon-B*

```
import java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import de.server.MacroClasses;
import net.sf.saxon.expr.Expression;
import net.sf.saxon.expr.StaticContext;
import net.sf.saxon.functions.ExtensionFunctionCall;
import net.sf.saxon.functions.FunctionLibrary;
import net.sf.saxon.om.StructuredQName;
import net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException;


public class OldXalanFunctionLibrary implements FunctionLibrary {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2216303509238422532L;

    public OldXalanFunctionLibrary() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAvailable(StructuredQName functionName, int arity) {
        String uri = functionName.getNamespaceURI();
        String local = functionName.getLocalName();
        if (uri.equals("xalan://de.server.macro") && (local.indexOf(".") > 0)) {
            Class c = MacroClasses.class;
            Method[] methods = c.getMethods();
            String searchName = local.substring(local.lastIndexOf(".")+1);  
            for (int i=0; i< methods.length; i++) {
                if (methods[i].getName().equals(searchName)) {
                    if (methods[i].getParameterTypes().length == arity) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Expression bind(StructuredQName functionName, Expression[] staticArgs, StaticContext env) throws XPathException {
        String uri = functionName.getNamespaceURI();
        String local = functionName.getLocalName();

        if (uri.equals("xalan://de.server.macro") && (local.indexOf(".") > 0)) {
            Class c = MacroClasses.class;
            Method[] methods = c.getMethods();
            Method m = null;
            String searchName = local.substring(local.lastIndexOf(".")+1);  
            for (int i=0; i< methods.length; i++) {
                //String name = methods[i].getName();
                if (methods[i].getName().equals(searchName)) {
                    if (methods[i].getParameterTypes().length == staticArgs.length) {
                        m = methods[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            AccessibleObject accessObj = (AccessibleObject)m;

            ExtensionFunctionCall fn;
            try {
                fn = (ExtensionFunctionCall)(c.newInstance());
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage());
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage());
            }

            fn.init(functionName, c, accessObj, env.getConfiguration());
            fn.setArguments(staticArgs);
            return fn;
        }
        return null;


    }

    @Override
    public FunctionLibrary copy() {
        OldXalanFunctionLibrary newLibrary = new OldXalanFunctionLibrary();
        return newLibrary;
    }

}
```

*Saxon-EE*

```
import java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import com.saxonica.expr.JavaExtensionFunctionCall;
import de.server.MacroClasses;
import net.sf.saxon.expr.Container;
import net.sf.saxon.expr.Expression;
import net.sf.saxon.expr.StaticContext;
import net.sf.saxon.functions.FunctionLibrary;
import net.sf.saxon.om.FunctionItem;
import net.sf.saxon.trans.SymbolicName;
import net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException;

public class OldXalanFunctionLibrary implements FunctionLibrary {

    public OldXalanFunctionLibrary() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAvailable(SymbolicName symName) {
        String uri = symName.getComponentName().getNamespaceBinding().getURI();
        String local = symName.getComponentName().getStructuredQName().getLocalPart();
        if (uri.equals("xalan://de.server.macro") && (local.indexOf(".") > 0)) {
            Class<MacroClasses> c = MacroClasses.class;
            Method[] methods = c.getMethods();
            String searchName = local.substring(local.lastIndexOf(".")+1);  
            for (int i=0; i< methods.length; i++) {
                if (methods[i].getName().equals(searchName)) {
                    if (methods[i].getParameterTypes().length == symName.getArity()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Expression bind(SymbolicName symName, Expression[] staticArgs, StaticContext context, Container cont) throws XPathException {
        String uri = symName.getComponentName().getNamespaceBinding().getURI();
        String local = symName.getComponentName().getStructuredQName().getLocalPart();

        if (uri.equals("xalan://de.server.macro") && (local.indexOf(".") > 0)) {
            Class<MacroClasses> c = MacroClasses.class;
            Method[] methods = c.getMethods();
            Method m = null;
            String searchName = local.substring(local.lastIndexOf(".")+1);  
            for (int i=0; i< methods.length; i++) {
                //String name = methods[i].getName();
                if (methods[i].getName().equals(searchName)) {
                    if (methods[i].getParameterTypes().length == symName.getArity()) {
                        m = methods[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            AccessibleObject accessObj = (AccessibleObject)m;

            JavaExtensionFunctionCall fn;
            try {
                fn = (JavaExtensionFunctionCall)(c.newInstance());
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage());
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage());
            }

            fn.init(symName.getComponentName().getStructuredQName(), c, accessObj);
            fn.setArguments(staticArgs);
            return fn;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public FunctionLibrary copy() {
        OldXalanFunctionLibrary newLibrary = new OldXalanFunctionLibrary();
        return newLibrary;
    }

    @Override
    public FunctionItem getFunctionItem(SymbolicName symName, StaticContext context, Container cont) throws XPathException {
        return null;
    }

}
```

My Wrapper-Class for calling my specific methods:

*Saxon-B*

```
package de.server;

import net.sf.saxon.functions.ExtensionFunctionCall;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

import de.macro.Format;
import de.macro.TrimLine;
import de.macro.data;
import de.macro.exception.JavaStaticTransformationException;

public class MacroClasses extends ExtensionFunctionCall {

    // data
    public static Document getXmlDoc() {
        return data.getXmlDoc();
    }

    public static void setVar(String name, String value) {
        data.setVar(name, value);
    }

    public static void setVar(String name, String value, String context) {
        data.setVar(name, value, context);
    }

    public static Node getVar(String name) {
        return data.getVar(name);
    }

    public static Node getVar(String name, String context) {
        return data.getVar(name, context);
    }

    public static void flush() {
        data.flush();
    }

    public static String countContextItems() {
        return data.countContextItems();
    }

    public static String getContextsAsString() {
        return data.getContextsAsString();
    }

    public static String countAllItems() {
        return data.countAllItems();
    }

    public static void setOutdatedTime(long aInterval) {
        data.setOutdatedTime(aInterval);
    }

    // Format
     public static String format(String aVarName, String aDataType, String aInputString, String aFormatType, String aPrecision) throws Exception {
         return Format.format(aVarName, aDataType, aInputString, aFormatType, aPrecision);
     }

     public static String format(String aVarName, String aDataType, String aInputString) throws Exception {
         return Format.format(aVarName, aDataType, aInputString);
     }

     public static String format(String aVarName, String aDataType, String aInputString, String aSwitchSign,
             String aFormatType, String aPrecision) throws Exception {
         return Format.format(aVarName, aDataType, aInputString, aSwitchSign, aFormatType, aPrecision);
     }

     public static String convertToEnglish(String aInputString) {
         return Format.convertToEnglish(aInputString);
     }

     public static String convertLastMonthsLast(String aInputString) {
         return Format.convertLastMonthsLast(aInputString);
     }

     public static String getCountSelected(String aVarName, String aValue)
             throws JavaStaticTransformationException {
         return Format.getCountSelected(aVarName, aValue);
     }

     public static String fill(String aVarName, String aInputString, String aFillChar, String aLength,
             String aDirection) throws JavaStaticTransformationException {
         return Format.fill(aVarName, aInputString, aFillChar, aLength, aDirection);
     }

     // TrimLine
     public static String process(String aInput, int aMaxLineLength) throws Exception {
         return TrimLine.process(aInput, aMaxLineLength);
     }
}
```

*Saxon-EE*

```
package de.server;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

import com.saxonica.expr.JavaExtensionFunctionCall;

import de.macro.Format;
import de.macro.TrimLine;
import de.macro.data;
import de.macro.exception.JavaStaticTransformationException;

public class MacroClasses extends JavaExtensionFunctionCall {

    // data
    public static Document getXmlDoc() {
        return data.getXmlDoc();
    }

    private static String convert4setVar(Object value) throws Exception {
        String setValue;

        if (value instanceof String)
        {
            setValue = (String)value;
        }
        else if (value instanceof net.sf.saxon.value.TextFragmentValue)
        {
            net.sf.saxon.value.TextFragmentValue newTextValue = (net.sf.saxon.value.TextFragmentValue)value;
            setValue = newTextValue.getStringValue();
        }
        else if (value instanceof Integer)
        {
            setValue = Integer.toString((Integer)value);
        }
        else if (value instanceof Double)
        {
            setValue = Double.toString((Double)value);
        }
        else if (value instanceof java.math.BigInteger)
        {
            java.math.BigInteger newIntegerValue = (java.math.BigInteger)value;
            setValue = newIntegerValue.toString();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Type for data.setVar not implemented: " + value.getClass().getName());
        }
        return setValue;
    }

    public static void setVar(String name, Object value) throws Exception {
        data.setVar(name, convert4setVar(value));
    }

    public static void setVar(String name, String value, String context) throws Exception {
        data.setVar(name, convert4setVar(value), context);
    }

    public static Node getVar(String name) {
        return data.getVar(name);
    }

    public static Node getVar(String name, String context) {
        return data.getVar(name, context);
    }

    public static void flush() {
        data.flush();
    }

    public static String countContextItems() {
        return data.countContextItems();
    }

    public static String getContextsAsString() {
        return data.getContextsAsString();
    }

    public static String countAllItems() {
        return data.countAllItems();
    }

    public static void setOutdatedTime(long aInterval) {
        data.setOutdatedTime(aInterval);
    }

    // Format
     public static String format(String aVarName, String aDataType, String aInputString, String aFormatType, String aPrecision) throws Exception {
         return Format.format(aVarName, aDataType, aInputString, aFormatType, aPrecision);
     }

     public static String format(String aVarName, String aDataType, String aInputString) throws Exception {
         return Format.format(aVarName, aDataType, aInputString);
     }

     public static String format(String aVarName, String aDataType, String aInputString, String aSwitchSign,
             String aFormatType, String aPrecision) throws Exception {
         return Format.format(aVarName, aDataType, aInputString, aSwitchSign, aFormatType, aPrecision);
     }

     public static String convertToEnglish(String aInputString) {
         return Format.convertToEnglish(aInputString);
     }

     public static String convertLastMonthsLast(String aInputString) {
         return Format.convertLastMonthsLast(aInputString);
     }

     public static String getCountSelected(String aVarName, String aValue)
             throws JavaStaticTransformationException {
         return Format.getCountSelected(aVarName, aValue);
     }

     public static String fill(String aVarName, String aInputString, String aFillChar, String aLength,
             String aDirection) throws JavaStaticTransformationException {
         return Format.fill(aVarName, aInputString, aFillChar, aLength, aDirection);
     }

     // TrimLine
     public static String process(String aInput, int aMaxLineLength) throws Exception {
         return TrimLine.process(aInput, aMaxLineLength);
     }

}
```

Now I don't need to modify any (cached/saved) XSLT-Stylesheets and it only catches the specific cases. So I can use the normal Saxon-Style calls for new generated Stylesheets but I'm downward compatible. And I hope I have no significant performance loss (my tests confirm this estimation till now).

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a subset of formats that will work across Xalan and Saxon. If you use what Xalan calls a "class format" namespace, for example

```
xmlns:String="xalan://java.util.Hashtable"
```

then you should be able to call static methods as, for example

```
String:valueOf($x)
```

in either product; in the case of Saxon you will need to set the configuration property FeatureKeys.ALLOW_OLD_JAVA_URI_FORMAT

Comment: and there would be no problem with "xalan://"?

Comment: and ideally I don't want to edit the old XSL-Stylesheets, so changing the namespace and the function calls would not fit my problem. Is there no way to use "macro:data.setVar(" in Saxon?

Comment: Only by writing your own customized version of the Java extension function factory class, which I wouldn't recommend.

Comment: Saxon first introduced extension function syntax to be compatible with early releases of xt and xalan, so it ignored everything before the "/". I think that Xalan does the same, "xalan://" is just an example.

Comment: With your mention of the "Java extension function factory class" I figured out my working solution (see my answer here). But I'm really interested why you "wouldn't recommend" it. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: The main reasons for not recommending it are (a) for many people it would tax their Java skills, and (b) for some of these deeper system programming interfaces, we don't actually do a great deal of testing. Also (c) these interfaces aren't always stable between releases. So congratulations.